# SQL Server Compact Edition is not showing in visual C# 2010 express

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm using win7 64-bits, just installed the visual C# 2010 express and I don't have the option for compact edition. What I should install to get it?[image]

I already install this:
    http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5783 (SQLCE 3.5)
    http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876 (SQLCE 4.0)

And I have both SQLCE in my "Uninstall Programs"

[image]

Comment: Would the sql ce tools fix it? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033cfb76-5382-44fb-bc7e-b3c8174832e2